# MongoDB: Aggregation/Grouping for poll votes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Am trying to create a poll results aggregation

I have two collections

**poll** - here is one document

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636027704f7a15587ef74f26"
  },
  "question": "question 1",
  "ended": false,
  "options": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "option": "option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "option": "option 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "option": "option 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Vote** - here is one document

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "635ed3210acbf9fd14af8fd1"
  },
  "poll_id": "636027704f7a15587ef74f26",
  "poll_option_id": "1",
  "user_id": "1"
}
```

and i want to perform an aggregate query to get poll results

so am doing the following query

```
db.vote.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $addFields: {
                poll_id: { "$toObjectId": "$poll_id" }
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "poll",
                localField: "poll_id",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "details"
            }
        },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: { poll_id: "$poll_id", poll_option_id: "$poll_option_id" },
                details: { $first: "$details" },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                question: { $arrayElemAt: ["$details.question", 0] }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                options: { $arrayElemAt: ["$details.options", 0] }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id.poll_id",
                poll_id: { $first: "$_id.poll_id" },
                question: { $first: "$question" },
                options: { $first: "$options" },
                optionsGrouped: {
                    $push: {
                        id: "$_id.poll_option_id",
                        count: "$count"
                    }
                },
                count: { $sum: "$count" }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

That is giving me this form of results

```
{ _id: ObjectId("636027704f7a15587ef74f26"),
  poll_id: ObjectId("636027704f7a15587ef74f26"),
  question: 'question 1',
  options: 
   [ { id: '1', option: 'option 1' },
     { id: '2', option: 'option 2' },
     { id: '3', option: 'option 3' } ],
  optionsGrouped: 
   [ { id: '1', count: 2 },
     { id: '2', count: 1 } ],
  count: 3 }
```

**So** what am interested in i want to have the results looking like ( like merging both options & options Group)

```
{ _id: ObjectId("636027704f7a15587ef74f26"),
  poll_id: ObjectId("636027704f7a15587ef74f26"),
  question: 'question 1',
  optionsGrouped: 
   [ { id: '1', option: 'option 1', count: 2 },
     { id: '2', option: 'option 2', count: 1 },
     { id: '3', option: 'option 3', count: 0 } ],
  count: 4 }
```

---

**Another question** is the DB structure acceptable overall or i can represent that in a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to group first and use the `$lookup` later, in order to fetch less data from the `poll` collection. After the `$lookup`, use `$map` with `$cond` to merge the arrays:

```
db.vote.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: {poll_id: {$toObjectId: "$poll_id"}, poll_option_id: "$poll_option_id"},
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.poll_id",
      counts: {
        $push: {count: "$count", option: {$concat: ["option ", "$_id.poll_option_id"]}}
      },
      countAll: {$sum: "$count"}
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "poll",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "poll"
  }},
  {$project: {poll: {$first: "$poll"}, counts: 1, countAll: 1}},
  {$project: {
      optionsGrouped: {
        $map: {
          input: "$poll.options",
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {$cond: [
                  {$gte: [{$indexOfArray: ["$counts.option", "$$this.option"]}, 0]},
                  {$arrayElemAt: ["$counts", {$indexOfArray: ["$counts.option", "$$this.option"]}]},
                  {count: 0}
              ]}
          ]}
        }
      },
      count: "$countAll",
      question: "$poll.question"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kRos5D55ttH)

Comment: thanks for you help, looks very good to me ; i have one more question if am going to pass a user to this query to add more property let's say **checked** and i need to add this checked inside the option group by true if the passed user is the same user from the vote document

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your request, please provide sample documents and requested results and I'll look at it

Comment: so am doing a request from a user (Frontend app) who wants to see all this polls and i need to mark the option he has chosen for each poll if he already done that, if u can see up there in the vote document i have user_id so given an input users id is there a way to map a true value in case the given user_id == option.user_id,  SO at the end will be like ``` [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("636027704f7a15587ef74f26"),
    "count": 3,
    "optionsGrouped": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        etc..
        "checked": "true",
      }
    ],
    "question": "question 1"
  }
]```

Comment: In this case use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NBUL3mbCebV)

Comment: i did some modification to the query and all good, only one tricky case when there is no votes the poll is not returning at all as $lookup is doing left join, so most probably i'll need to query the poll collection do the join then will do the same logic; most probably will not be easy from that direction, i'll try and will post here the sol if was succeeded

Comment: i have tried to invert the joins, but the problem is that the aggregation now is on the second level after the join, kinda confusing to me; u have any idea what shall be done

i just want to get all polls even if they don't have votes, currently only getting one's that have votes

sorry man, coming from relational db background, so terms & how the queries are done here are different and confuses me

Answer (score 0):

I had reworked the query to match my desires

and this query is achieving the question i have asked

```
db.poll.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      _id: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "poll_vote",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "poll_id",
      as: "votes"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            count: {
              $size: "$votes"
            },
            options: {
              $map: {
                input: "$options",
                as: "option",
                in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$option",
                    {
                      count: {
                        $size: {
                          $slice: [
                            {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$votes",
                                as: "v",
                                cond: {
                                  $and: [
                                    {
                                      $eq: [
                                        "$$v.poll_option_id",
                                        "$$option._id"
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            0,
                            100
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      checked: {
                        $toBool: {
                          $size: {
                            $slice: [
                              {
                                $filter: {
                                  input: "$votes",
                                  as: "v",
                                  cond: {
                                    $and: [
                                      {
                                        $eq: [
                                          "$$v.user_id",
                                          2
                                        ]
                                      },
                                      {
                                        $eq: [
                                          "$$v.poll_option_id",
                                          "$$option._id"
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              0,
                              100
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "in": {
            _id: "$_id",
            question: "$question",
            count: "$$count",
            ended: "$ended",
            options: "$$options"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      answered: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$options",
          initialValue: false,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.checked",
                  true
                ]
              },
              true,
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```